# select a word in class with vim, one more strikethrough redundant

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

```
struct Base {
    struct Base *next;
    .....
};
    Base baseObj;
    baseObj->next;
```

I would like to select a word in vim, here is some selection "[* # gd ve]", I'm looking forward to the result is "baseObj", but the real result is "baseObj-", 
Especially when in use cscope to lookup define and caller.
how can i get the "baseObj" as i excepted?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the dash for the `&isk` option in order to ignore `-` when doing word selection.

You'll have to do it only for programming languages, as `-` may act as hyphen in texts when you'll want to control spelling.

```
" in $HOME/ftplugin/c.vim, java.vim, etc
setlocal isk-=-
```

Or with functions like [`lh#ft#is_text()` from lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/ft.vim#L52):

```
" .vimrc, untested
augroup FixDash
  au!
  " I'm not sure these are the best auto command events to use
  au BufRead,BufNewFile * if !lh#ft#is_text(&ft) | setl isk-=- | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: I add this cmd below to my .vimrc,
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile,BufWinEnter *.cc,*.cpp,*.[ch],*.hpp,*.java setlocal isk-=- 
and it really does works.
Thanks very much,

Comment: A tip: never define autocommands outside a group you haven't just cleared. Otherwise, if you reload your .vimrc, the autocommand will be trigerred twice after first reload, three times after the second, and so on.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need the `BufWinEnter` event. `isk` is a local option.

Comment: This is the place where I missed, Thanks again